# analyze JsonObject from Facebook Graph API Error

Tags: android, json

I had error

> org.json.JSONException: No value for data

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpzks.png)

I had tried many ways but I can't solve it. Please help me to fix it. 
It is possible to use Gson API to parse `JsonObject` above to java `Object`?

Comment: Welcome! Please post your code as text, not as a linked image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `posts` before.

```
JSONArray data = responde.getJSONObject("posts").getJSONArray("data");
```

instead of

```
JSONArray data = responde.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
```

This should work for this scenario, but you really need to check for non existent keys or values.

Comment: But, JSONArraydata=responde.getJSONObject("posts").getJSONArray("data"); can't getJSONObject("posts") . syntax error